# Spring Boot log file can be set by application.properties but not by System.setProperty("logging.file",name)

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

I have a Spring boot application which can read an hard coded log file name from application.properties like this:

**Option 1: ( working fine )**

```
 logging.file=C\\outputFolder\\fileName3.log
```

**Option 2: ( not working )**

For some reason if i set it as

```
  System.setProperty("logging.file", "C:\\outputFolder\\fileName2.log");
```

it doesn't work, i have a very similar Spring boot application which reads the file name using Option 2, any idea what is missing here ?

I'm using slf4j in the following way:

```
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the property value after logging configuration is done by spring boot, calling   `System.setProperty("logging.file", "C:\\outputFolder\\fileName2.log")` won't take effect.

you can read the file location from the second app using `System.getProperty("logging.file")`

Comment: Thanks slimane, i just moved the line   System.setProperty("logging.file", "C:\\outputFolder\\fileName2.log");  to be before         SpringApplication.run(DBApplication.class, args);
and it is working fine now - thanks !